# Javascript extract regular expression from string

Tags: javascript, regex

I've tried a few ways of doing this and I can't figure out why my .match always returns null. Given the string below how can I extract the 04-Jun-2017 into it's own variable?

```
var str = "I need the only the    date 04-Jun-2017\n"

str.replace(/\n/g,' ');
var date = str.match(/^[01][0-9]-(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)-\d{4}$/);
alert(date)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, `str.replace(/\n/g,' ');` does not modify `str` var since strings are immutable. Then, you do not need the anchors `^` and `$`, as the date is inside the string, it is not equal to the string itself. Also, you need to match days from `1` to `31`, but `[01][0-9]` only matches from `00` to `19`.

You may consider using

```js
var str = "I need the only the    date 04-Jun-2017\n"
var date = str.match(/\b\d{1,2}-(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)-\d{4}\b/i);
if (date) {
  console.log(date[0]);
}
```

The anchors are replaced with word boundaries `\b` and the day part is changed into `\d{1,2}` matching any 1 or 2 digits. The `i` modifier will make the pattern case insensitive.

Comment: Your code is exactly what I needed.  Too be honest I didn't even know about \b and have very little experience with the Regex.  I will say I had no idea strings are immutable as your put it?  The str.replace(/\n/g,' '); definitely does remove the new line.  My own solution before yours was to replace the \n with " " split everything into tokens with .split(" ") then loop through and match using my jacked up regex.  Bottom line, your way is much better.

Answer (score 0):

At first you should be more clear about your question.
Second here's what may be the answer

```
var str = "I need the only the    date 04-Jun-2017\n"
var result  = str.replace('I need the only the    ','');
alert(result);
```

See how the `.replace(valueToSearch,valueToReplace)` function needs two parameters, first is the text to replace, so what ever you put inside it will search for inside the string, the second parameter is the value that it will replace it with, so in case you want to get rid of it just place an empty string.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and you're write I should have written that more clear, instead it was in haste.  Also your answer won't work for me because the text surrounding the date will change(I guess I didn't specify that), therefore, had to go with the RegEx answer.